# Canvas image not loading correctly in Firefox unless cached

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using a bitmap font in HTML canvas, however when you first load the page in Firefox (or if cache is disabled, for example in DevTools), the font does not appear.

Here is the page: --snip--

First, the font image itself is loaded:.

```js
var font = new Image();       
font.src = "img/fontwhite.png";  
font.onload = loadFontColours;
```

When it has loaded, I load the tinted versions of it into the colour array.

```js
    colourLookupTable[0].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 240, 240, 240);
    colourLookupTable[1].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 242, 178, 51);
    colourLookupTable[2].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 229, 127, 216);
    colourLookupTable[3].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 153, 178, 242);
    colourLookupTable[4].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 222, 222, 108);
    colourLookupTable[5].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 127, 204, 25);
    colourLookupTable[6].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 242, 178, 204);
    colourLookupTable[7].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 76, 76, 76);
    colourLookupTable[8].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 153, 153, 153);
    colourLookupTable[9].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 76, 153, 178);
    colourLookupTable[10].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 178, 102, 229);
    colourLookupTable[11].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 51, 102, 204);
    colourLookupTable[12].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 127, 102, 76);
    colourLookupTable[13].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 87, 166, 78);
    colourLookupTable[14].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 204, 76, 76);
    colourLookupTable[15].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 25, 25, 25);
```

In Chrome, you can see that the font appears perfectly fine, cached or not. However, in Firefox, it does not appear unless cached. Am I missing something obvious?

Full code:

```js
$(function() {
    var termWidth = 51;
    var termHeight = 19;
    var textScale = 2;
    var pixelWidth = 1 * 6 * textScale;
    var pixelHeight = 1.5 * 6 * textScale;
    var fontSize = 8;

    var container = $("#term");
    var canvas = $("#term canvas#main");
    var ctx = $("#term canvas#main")[0].getContext("2d");

    canvas.hide();    
    container.hide();

    var pixels = [];

    var colourLookupTable = [{
        name: "white",
        realColour: "#F0F0F0",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "orange",
        realColour: "#F2B233",
        fontBuf: null
    }, {
        name: "magenta",
        realColour: "#E57FD8",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "lightBlue",
        realColour: "#99B2F2",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "yellow",
        realColour: "#DEDE6C",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "lime",
        realColour: "#7FCC19",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "pink",
        realColour: "#F2B2CC",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "grey",
        simplifiedSpelling: "gray",
        realColour: "#4C4C4C",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "lightGrey",
        simplifiedSpelling: "lightGray",
        realColour: "#999999",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "cyan",
        realColour: "#4C99B2",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "purple",
        realColour: "#B266E5",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "blue",
        realColour: "#3366CC",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "brown",
        realColour: "#7F664C",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "green",
        realColour: "#57A64E",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "red",
        realColour: "#CC4C4C",
        fontBuf:null
    }, {
        name: "black",
        realColour: "#191919",
        realColourBg: "#000000",
        fontBuf:null
    }]; 

    var font = new Image();       
    font.src = "img/fontwhite.png";  
    font.onload = loadFontColours;

    function loadFontColours() {        
        console.log("loading font colours");
        console.log(font);
        var start = new Date().getTime();

        colourLookupTable[0].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 240, 240, 240);
        colourLookupTable[1].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 242, 178, 51);
        colourLookupTable[2].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 229, 127, 216);
        colourLookupTable[3].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 153, 178, 242);
        colourLookupTable[4].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 222, 222, 108);
        colourLookupTable[5].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 127, 204, 25);
        colourLookupTable[6].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 242, 178, 204);
        colourLookupTable[7].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 76, 76, 76);
        colourLookupTable[8].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 153, 153, 153);
        colourLookupTable[9].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 76, 153, 178);
        colourLookupTable[10].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 178, 102, 229);
        colourLookupTable[11].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 51, 102, 204);
        colourLookupTable[12].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 127, 102, 76);
        colourLookupTable[13].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 87, 166, 78);
        colourLookupTable[14].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 204, 76, 76);
        colourLookupTable[15].fontBuf = generateTintImage(font, 25, 25, 25);

        var end = new Date().getTime();

        console.log("loaded font colours, " + (end - start) + "ms");
        console.log(colourLookupTable);
        drawAll();
    }  
    console.log("font src");

    function initScreen() {
        pixelWidth = 1 * 6 * textScale;
        pixelHeight = 1.5 * 6 * textScale;

        container.css("border-width", 12 * textScale);
        container.css("font-size", 8 * textScale);
        canvas.attr("width", termWidth * pixelWidth + textScale * 4);
        canvas.attr("height", termHeight * pixelHeight + textScale * 4);
        canvas.width(termWidth * pixelWidth + textScale * 4);
        canvas.height(termHeight * pixelHeight + textScale * 4);

        ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

        for (var y = 0; y < termHeight; y++) {
            pixels[y] = [];
            for (var x = 0; x < termWidth; x++) {
                pixels[y][x] = new Pixel();
                pixels[y][x].textColour = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
                pixels[y][x].backgroundColour = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
                pixels[y][x].text = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*96) + 32);
            }
        }

        //canvas.fadeIn(1250);
       // container.slideDown(1250);
        canvas.show();
        container.show();
    }

    function drawAll() {         
        for (var y = 0; y < termHeight; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < termWidth; x++) {
                pixels[y][x].textColour = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
                pixels[y][x].backgroundColour = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
                pixels[y][x].text = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*96) + 32);
                pixels[y][x].draw(x, y);
            }
        }        
    }

    var charsX = 16;
    var charsY = 6;
    var charWidth = 8;
    var charHeight = 8;

    function Pixel() {
        this.textColour = 0xE;
        this.backgroundColour = 0xF;
        this.text = "";

        // lemmmy's _ but sassy cc rendering thing(tm)

        this.draw = function(x, y) {
            this.text = this.text.substring(0, 1);

            var clt = colourLookupTable[this.backgroundColour];
            ctx.fillStyle = clt.realColourBg ? clt.realColourBg : clt.realColour;
            ctx.fillRect(x * pixelWidth + textScale * 2, y * pixelHeight + textScale * 2, pixelWidth, pixelHeight);

            clt = colourLookupTable[this.textColour];

            if (font != null && clt.fontBuf != null) {
                var char = this.text.charCodeAt(0);

                if (char > 32 && char < 127) {
                    var fx = (char - 32) % charsX;
                    var fy = Math.floor((char - 32) / charsX);

                    ctx.drawImage(clt.fontBuf, fx * charWidth, fy * charHeight,
                                  charWidth, charHeight, 
                                  x * pixelWidth + textScale * 2, y * pixelHeight + textScale * 2,
                                  charWidth * textScale, charHeight * textScale);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function generateRGBKs( img ) {
        var w = img.width;
        var h = img.height;
        var rgbks = [];

        var fcanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        fcanvas.width = w;
        fcanvas.height = h;

        var fctx = fcanvas.getContext("2d");
        fctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

        var pixels = fctx.getImageData( 0, 0, w, h ).data;

        for ( var rgbI = 0; rgbI < 4; rgbI++ ) {
            var fcanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            fcanvas.width  = w;
            fcanvas.height = h;

            var fctx = fcanvas.getContext('2d');
            fctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
            var to = fctx.getImageData( 0, 0, w, h );
            var toData = to.data;

            for (
                    var i = 0, len = pixels.length;
                    i < len;
                    i += 4
            ) {
                toData[i  ] = (rgbI === 0) ? pixels[i  ] : 0;
                toData[i+1] = (rgbI === 1) ? pixels[i+1] : 0;
                toData[i+2] = (rgbI === 2) ? pixels[i+2] : 0;
                toData[i+3] =                pixels[i+3]    ;
            }

            fctx.putImageData( to, 0, 0 );

            var imgComp = new Image();
            imgComp.src = fcanvas.toDataURL();

            rgbks.push( imgComp );
        }

        return rgbks;
    }

    function generateTintImage( img, red, green, blue ) {
        var buff = document.createElement( "canvas" );
        buff.width  = img.width;
        buff.height = img.height;
        var rgbks = generateRGBKs(img);

        var fctx  = buff.getContext("2d");

        fctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        fctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
        fctx.drawImage( rgbks[3], 0, 0 );

        fctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
        if ( red > 0 ) {
            fctx.globalAlpha = red   / 255.0;
            fctx.drawImage( rgbks[0], 0, 0 );
        }
        if ( green > 0 ) {
            fctx.globalAlpha = green / 255.0;
            fctx.drawImage( rgbks[1], 0, 0 );
        }
        if ( blue > 0 ) {
            fctx.globalAlpha = blue  / 255.0;
            fctx.drawImage( rgbks[2], 0, 0 );
        }

        return buff;
    }

    initScreen();

    //setInterval(drawAll, 500);
});
```

Comment: Without debugging the code, sounds like it is a timing issue and you do not properly wait somewhere that the image has loaded first. You can debug this by inspecting the loaded image in the JavaScript breakpoint when you hit the error situation (you have invalid image object).

Comment: The image object is valid. After intense debugging, it appears just fine exactly when I'm drawing it.

Comment: Your var imgComp = new Image(); is also async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, K3N! By only calling generateRGBKs once and adding a callback to its imgComp, the issue was resolved.

```
function loadFontColours() {        
    console.log("loading font colours");
    console.log(font);
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var rgbks = generateRGBKs(font, function() {
        colourLookupTable[0].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 240, 240, 240);
        colourLookupTable[1].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 242, 178, 51);
        colourLookupTable[2].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 229, 127, 216);
        colourLookupTable[3].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 153, 178, 242);
        colourLookupTable[4].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 222, 222, 108);
        colourLookupTable[5].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 127, 204, 25);
        colourLookupTable[6].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 242, 178, 204);
        colourLookupTable[7].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 76, 76, 76);
        colourLookupTable[8].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 153, 153, 153);
        colourLookupTable[9].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 76, 153, 178);
        colourLookupTable[10].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 178, 102, 229);
        colourLookupTable[11].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 51, 102, 204);
        colourLookupTable[12].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 127, 102, 76);
        colourLookupTable[13].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 87, 166, 78);
        colourLookupTable[14].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 204, 76, 76);
        colourLookupTable[15].fontBuf = generateTintImage(rgbks, font, 25, 25, 25);

        var end = new Date().getTime();

        console.log("loaded font colours, " + (end - start) + "ms");
        console.log(colourLookupTable);
        drawAll();
    });     
}
```